# Direct runnig python GUI scrips (wxpython)

Tags: python, wxpython

Hello Guys! I started learning python GUI development. Let's say I have this script:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

win = wx.Frame(None, title="Simple Editor", size=(410, 335))
bkg = wx.Panel(win)

loadButton = wx.Button(bkg, label="Open")
saveButton = wx.Button(bkg, label="Save")
fileName = wx.TextCtrl(bkg)
contents = wx.TextCtrl(bkg, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)

hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
hbox.Add(fileName, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
hbox.Add(loadButton, proportion=0, flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)
hbox.Add(saveButton, proportion=0, flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)

vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
vbox.Add(hbox, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
vbox.Add(contents, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT |wx.BOTTOM | wx.RIGHT, border=5) 

bkg.SetSizer(vbox)
win.Centre()
win.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This script does nothing, just shows windows and etc. To run this script, basically I do from terminal by:

```
python gui_test.py
```

How can I run it directly, without invoking terminal, I mean running just clicking with mouse?

Comment: try to use OOP with wxPython...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Rename `gui_test.py` -> `gui_test.pyw`
2. Double click

[.pyw](http://filext.com/file-extension/PYW) is the fancy windows way of telling the python script to execute without also opening a console

---

For linux systems, make the script executable:

```
chmod a+x gui_test.py
```

Also, don't forget to include the "shebang" line at the top of any executable script. This allows you to run the script without having to specify the interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then from a terminal:

```
./gui_test.py
```

Comment: I run ubuntu linux, so nothin occured

Comment: In ubuntu you normally launch python scripts from the terminal, otherwise you would package them up with something like pyinstaller